# Android: Admob resource not found @integer/google_play_services_version

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

it may be a duplicated question but didn't mention about the original location of the project. I have looked through original location of that project and can't see value/integer.xml file so I think i have no problem with import the project on to my workspace. The file didn't even exist in the original location

How to get that integer.xml file back

Comment: have u import google play lib in your workspace and using it to your project

Comment: Yes, through import -> existing code into workspace -> copy to workspace. I even add jar library under the build path.

Comment: have u use in your project manifest  <meta-data 
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: Yes that is the part i have error where it say no resource found. So I look at the imported project and seeing no integer.xml nor version.xml in it.

Comment: what is your mail is i will send u right playstore lib that u import in worksapce and use it

Comment: `add jar library under the build path` here is the problem. You need to reference it as an Android Library project, see described here https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject @Simon

Comment: the file name is value/version.xml not value/integer.xml in google lib project. It have                         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="google_play_services_version">some number</integer>
</resources>

Comment: That file not exist as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. update SDK
2. import googleplay project to workspace
3. import googleplay project as a lib to your project

you can visit [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).